# NodeJS (or) PM2 stuck but no errors anywhere

Tags: node.js, pm2, ubuntu-20.04

I am running a NodeJS process using PM2. The machine itself is a Ubuntu 20.x with 4 cores and 16Gig Ram. The process gets stuck after some time. Infact all 4 cores gets stuck

I tried looking into Pm2 logs, application logs, Ubuntu sys logs, tried PM2-probe but couldn't find out what is the root cause.

- One thing to note here is all 4 cores are fully utilized ( 90 to 100%)
- Memory is 50% utilized
- Healp memory 85% utilized

Could someone provide some pointers or install some utilities to find out the root cause. This happens every 30 to 45 mins